# What is this cable called?

Tags: cable

What is [this cable](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/cable.jpg) called?

[image]

It plugs into the Lenovo desktop motherboard, and powers my SATA SSD.

The left plug connects to the motherboard, and the right plug connects to the SSD.

I am one HDD power cable short, and I want a splitter, or double adapter, so I can power 2 SATA drives off one connection the motherboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4-pin connector is called a ATX12V connector. The one on the right is a SATA Power Connector.

Comment: Thanks xxl3ww. Do you know if I can buy a splitter? I can't find any on eBay. Lenovo want me to pay $80 for their splitter.

Comment: I guess I can just buy a SATA power connector splitter.

Comment: That would be your best bet, or is there any MOLEX connections? You could get a MOLEX to SATA